# Android AVD throwing an error that HAXM is not installed

Tags: android

I created an AVD with minimal configuration but it shows an error message that HAXM not installed.

Comment: Have you tried installing HAXM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Android Studio IDE provides Virtualisation Technology for simulation for better and speedy performance.

For that purpose you have to install an patch of "HAXM". Virtualisation patch available at Android Download Manager.

after successful installation of that patch you have to enable the Virtualisation from system BIOS.

after that simulator will work surely with better and speedy performance.

Answer (score 0):

Worthy note:

Some other programs use virtualisation while you would not expect them to, thus preventing android studio to install haxm
(namely in my case was avast antivirus)